# mongoose connection url explanation

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

`var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/swag-shop');`

I've a really quick question, I'm kinda new to the database stuff but what does that url refers to ? 
don't blame I'm just new..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**mongodb://localhost/** -- it will connect to mongodb instance running on local host, 
**swag-shop** -- this is the name of your DB

Make sure that mongo db is running on localhost that can be done by typing mongod in command prompt